# How to design a game in Unity3D which is viable for patching?

Tags: unity-game-engine, patch

I was designing my open world RPG's architecture (I am creating it for fun, I don't intend it to be a hit game :D ), and had to stop it, because I ran into a serious wall.

If a create a big open world game, then its size will be big.

Let's imagine that my game has a launcher, which automatically updates itself, when a new patch is found.

Downloading the whole game again is not acceptable, because if there is a minor bugfix, who would download a whole game again, if there is only a minor change?

So somehow I have to make an architecture which is patchable, so if there is an update, my launcher will only download changed files and not the whole client.

When I build my game, 90 % (if not more) of the game data is in one Program Debug Database.

And when I look at a game, for example World of Warcraft, its files are organized in compressed directories. And if there is a minor fix in one zone's particular place (like a tree is missing), they don't have to update the whole game, and not even the whole map, and not even the whole zone.

Instead they only have to update the file, which determines that (for example) 20x20 meter area in the world where is the bug.

So let's get practical with a simple example:

I have one scene with a big terrain in it, and I have to fix a little part of it.

How can I update my released client's buggy parts without downloading the whole client again?

Thanks for your help in advance! :)

Comment: if you think the question is too broad, click "flag" for closure

Comment: Tudvari - (1) just use asset bundles, it is totally built-in to Unity for this purpose (2) nobody cares about patching. it's an irrelevant issue. just issue ordinary updates.

Comment: you need to CLICK AN ANSWER, op, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do so. One of the most common ways in [unity-3d](/questions/tagged/unity-3d) is by [asset-bundles](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.html). This would allow you to update your game in a similar manner as for example wow.

There are also plenty of assets available in the app store. The one I personally use is [M2HPatcher](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/m2hpatcher-the-unity-patching-solution.111671/) this mainly as it was free at the time. I am not sure if it is still

Comment: I found M2HPatcher but it's no longer available because the owner didn't want to sell a product which has flaws.

Comment: I saw some examples of Asset Bundles, but I don't know if it's what I want.

For example I have 2 objects in the scene, and I want to make a "patch", which deletes 1 object, edits the other, and add a new one somewhere. If I can't place scripts in asset bundles, then how can I do this?

Comment: @Tudvari Loading scripts from asset bundles is not supported on Windows Store Apps and Windows Phone. Furthermore it is perfectly possible. Then again, you could just remove the object from the asset bundle. If you write generic/re-usable code in a OO way, you should not often have problems with it.